# Dictionary seemingly pulling same value for all keys (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dictionary in which each key is a number 0-7. Each item is a collection of two number values. For each value in the dataset I am iterating through, the code checks which key 1-7 it belongs to, pulls the appropriate collection from the dictionary, adds the data to the collection, and inserts the collection back into the dictionary. It also adds every value to the 0 key in the dictionary, so that at the end the 0 key will contain a grand total i.e. the output should look like this:

```
Key:Value

0:100
1:20
2:10
3:10
4:20
5:10
6:5
7:25
```

The problem that I am having is that the output is something like:
    Key:Value

```
0:100
1:100
2:100
3:100
4:100
5:100
6:100
7:100
```

It seems like each time I pull a collection from the dictionary using a key it, pulls the same collection regardless of key and then adds the data to that collection.

Dictionary:

```
For region = 0 To 7
    regDict.Add region, blankColl
Next region
```

Adding items:

```
            thisRegion = 'some number 1-7 found elsewhere

            ' pull the collection from the regDict
            Set subtotalColl = regDict.Item(thisRegion)

            subtotalSales = subtotalColl("Item") + thisSales

            subtotalColl.Remove ("Item")
            subtotalColl.Add Item:=subtotalSales, Key:="Item"

            ' replace the collection for thisRegion with the new one
            regDict.Remove thisRegion
            regDict.Add thisRegion, subtotalColl

            ' ----------- "region 0" gets every record no matter
            ' ----------- what the region of the record is

            ' pull the collection at 0 from the regDict
            Set zeroSubtotalColl = regDict.Item(0)

            subtotalSales = zeroSubtotalColl("Item") + thisSales

            zeroSubtotalColl.Remove ("Item")
            zeroSubtotalColl.Add Item:=subtotalSales, Key:="Item"

            ' replace the collection for Region 0 with the new one
            regDict.Remove 0
            regDict.Add 0, zeroSubtotalColl
```

The problem is that when I check the dictionary after all of this is done, every collection contains the same values! Even if I debug within this, `zeroSubtotalColl` from `regDict(0)` contains the the "new" value that I just put back into `regDict(thisRegion)` as `subtotalColl`.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`blankColl` is always a reference to the same collection, and you add it for each key, so all the "values" point to the same object.

Current:

```
Set regdict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Set blankColl = New Collection 'guessing here what you did...

For region = 0 To 7
    regdict.Add region, blankColl
Next region

regdict(1).Add "hello"
Debug.Print regdict(7).Count '>>1 oops - should be empty!
```

Fix:

```
For region = 0 To 7
    regdict.Add region, New Collection
Next region

regdict(1).Add "hello"
Debug.Print regdict(7).Count '>>0 still empty!
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand the issue. However. now I'm getting an `invalid procedure call or argument` error later on when trying to pull that collection out of the dictionary to edit.

Comment: A little bit of error handling trickery fixed that. Thanks so much for your help!